# Why does iTunes Connect reject all images for App Store saying they are wrong size?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Here's what the error looks like for every single image file I drop into iTunes Connect for my app screens.

[image: error message]

Here is the list of image sizes that supposedly will work (when you click that Learn More link you see this):

[image: acceptable sizes]

Here are the details of the screenshot I grabbed using Command-S while simulator was running.  Notice that the size seems to match one of the required dimensions.  That was while running an iPhone 6 simulator.

[image: fail size]

Here's another one I tried with slightly different dimensions that is supposedly acceptable also, but fails.  I have tried numerous ones and none will upload.
This one's while running a 5s simualtor:
[image: fail again]

This is really annoying since I'm just attempting to release my app but I'm stuck on this (should be) simple thing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iPhone 5 is a 4 inch display, not a 4.7 or 5.5 inch display (iPhone 6 & 6+).  The images you have meet the requirements for a 4 inch screen shot, but you are attempting to load these images for the 5.5 inch display.

You can either upload an iPhone 6+ screen shot and iTunesConnect will automatically scale this image for other screen sizes, or you can select "Other sizes" in iTunesConnect and upload specific screenshots for the specific sizes.

Comment: Thanks. I will fire up the 6+ emulator take snapshots and try it. If it works I will mark this as answer.

Comment: That was it. I ran the 6+ emulator, set the hardware to 100% size on screen and took a snapshot and dragged and dropped the image in. FYI--  I also tried setting the emulator to 50% size on screen and took a snapshot and it did _not_ work.  Thanks again.